# Evaluate $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(1, 2) $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $ f $ and $ g $ be functions of $ x $ and $ y. $ Given that $ f(1, 2) = 2 $ and $ g(1, 2) = 1. $ Also at $ (1, 2)$, $df = -2dx + 5dy, dg = 4dx - 3dy. $

$ z $ is a function of $ (x, y) $ defined implicitly by $ z^2f + zg + x - y = 0 $ with $ z(1, 2) = -1. $ What is $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(1, 2)? $

Comment: Have you tried differentiating your expression for the implicit function?

Answer (score 0):

The implicit function is a quadratic polynomial in $z$ so it is not difficult to write $z$ explicitly as a function of $x$ (and $y$ but you can treat that as a constant). When taking the partial derivative of that function with respect to $x$ you can use the expressions for $df$ and $dg.$

Comment: I don't understand your point, so you mean solving $ z $ using the quadratic formula? Because I got $ z = \frac{-g \pm \sqrt{g^2 - 4f(x - y)}}{2f} $

Comment: That's correct but be careful to intepret the letter $f$ as $f(x,y);$ the $(x-y)$ behind it is not an argument but a factor. Now compute the partial derivative of that $z$ with respect to $x,$ using your knowledge about the partial derivatives of $g$ and $f$ with respect to $x.$ If you are annoyed by the plusminus sign you can choose the correct sign from the start by considering the values at the point $(1,2).$